# Jquery dialog in rails 3 with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

i had a index page with url as www.exa,com/users/jude.In that page i want to submit a from which appears from popup dialog.The action of the popup is going to send_message,Whenever i submits, via ajax  the data gets stored but not the page gets reflected.

My controller

```
 def send_message
    @message = current_user.messages.build(params[:message])
    @message.receiver_id = @user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html {redirect_to user_url(current_user)}
      format.js
      end 
    end
  end
```

View  file

```
%div.jqmWindow#dialog
  %div.dialog_content
-form_for Message.new,:url=>'users_message_path',:remote=>true do |f|
      =hidden_field_tag :id,@user.login
      =f.text_area 'content',:rows => 10, :cols => 25
      =f.submit 'Send'
```

My js.erb

```
$('#dialog').html("hello")
```

Problem is ajax is requestuing the action /users/send_message and not /users/jude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we use haml as a markup, then we have all the files should have .html.haml naming conventions, since views with the .html.haml extension will automatically use Haml.

Now in format.js file we can our updated or inserted data to show

$('#dialog').html('<%= escape_javascript "You have successfully sent your message to #{@message.receiver_id.login}"%>')

Now the data gets inserted via ajax calls